# How to call parent presenter in user control presenter MVP pattern

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mvp, presenter

I am using MVP pattern to develop a Windows Form using c#.

I have a presenter `MainPresenter` which has reference of `InfoPresenter` so `MainPresenter` can access `InfoPresenter`'s methods.

Now I want to access `MainPresenter`'s methods in `InfoPresenter`. If I give reference of `MainPresenter` into `InfoPresenter` the application will break with following error.

> System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'

Following is the code that is breaking:

`MainPresenter`

```
class MainPresenter : IMainPresenter
{
    private IInfoPresenter _infoPresenter;

    public MainPresenter(IInfoPresenter infoPresenter)
    {
        _infoPresenter = infoPresenter;
    }
}
```

`InfoPresenter`

```
class InfoPresenter : IInfoPresenter
{
    private IMainPresenter _mainPresenter;

    public InfoPresenter(IMainPresenter mainPresenter)
    {
        _mainPresenter = mainPresenter;
    }
}
```

If I remove the reference of `MainPresenter` from second class (`InfoPresenter`) it will work fine, but then I want to access some of its (`MainPresenter`) method into `InfoPresenter` and vice versa.

Comment: What do you mean by "the application will break"? What do you see exactly? A compilation error? If so, what is it?

Comment: @o_weisman `System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'` getting this error when I run code.

Comment: You're probably stuck in an endless creation loop. We need to see your Presenter classes creation code. How do you construct these instances?

Comment: yes exactly. Not getting you what you need? These are the presenter classes and I am instantiating other presenter in constructor.

Comment: How can you even write code that creates these classes? One of them has to have a constructor that doesn't require the other one or else it's not even writable (I'd love to see how you managed to create them). Make one of the constructors empty and use a different method like setPresenter(IMainPresenter parent) to set its parent after creation.

Comment: Try to put common methods in different class and access it in these both classes OR keep it in one class and call it in another. Both way dependency injection might cause stackoverflow.